# Updating Post Meta with Backbone and the REST API

Tags: plugin-json-api, backbone, rest-api

I'm getting started with a project that is making use of Backbone and the WP REST API, but I"m having a little trouble.

Using the built in API JS for models and collections allows me to pretty easily update a post title or content. All I have to do is call:

```
this.model.set({title: 'New Title'});
this.model.save();
```

And everything works really well. But for post meta, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to update an entry to the database. Does anyone know how to go about taking a post model in Backbone, and updating it's meta data?

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question, but the WP REST API does have an option called post_meta to enter the post_meta when the post is created, and it also let's you retrieve it. http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-meta-for-a-post

Comment: I saw a talk this weekend that showed off Backbone - http://tunedin.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/backbone-avl.pdf. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
var parentId = 96; // the post id
var metaData = new wp.api.collections.PostMeta('', {parent: parentId});
metaData.fetch()
  .done(function(data) {
    var someKey = data.findWhere({key: 'someKey'});
    someKey.set('value', 'newValue');

    someKey.save({parent: parentId});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the models api as well:

```
var post = new wp.api.models.Post( { id: 1 } );
post.fetch();
post.setMeta('metaKey', 'metaValue');
// Or multiple metas at one time:
post.setMetas({metaKeyOne: 'metaValueOne', metaKeyTwo: 'metaValueTwo'});
post.save()
```

For this to work , the meta must be registered for REST API with `register_post_meta` and `show_in_rest` argument set to `true`.
Here is an example:

```
add_action(
    'init',
    function() {
        register_post_meta('my_post_type', 'my_meta_key', ['show_in_rest' => true, 'single' => true]);
    }
);
```